# Git: Command for cancel a commit

Tags: git

When I work, I often meet with this workflow:

1. Doing something.
2. Someone comes to my desk and ask something, I must move to another branch for checking.
3. I commit code on this current branch and checkout another branch.
4. When I finish, I checkout old branch and continue to work.

This workflow has a disadvantage: it generates a dummy commit in my system. My question is: how can I avoid this situation? For example, when I come back to work, I will cancel previous commit?

Comment: use stash https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: [how to undo last commits in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-last-commits-in-git) you can find your answer here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to the two existing answers (`git reset` and `git stash`), I personally just ignore the extra commit (which almost has a commit message of `wip`...) until I'm ready to push the change somewhere remote, e.g. to github to create a pull request.

At that point, I use `git rebase -i` to look at all the commits I've got in that branch, and work out which commits I want to push - squashing commits together and rewording commit messages as required.

I've personally found this to be easier to use than `git stash`, as I typically find I lose track of what stashes are meant to be about. (My fault rather than a flaw in git, but the effect is still bad.) I suspect that `git reset` would be fine too, but as I often have to rebase *anyway* before a final merge - e.g. to react to code review comments - I have `git rebase` as a more mentally efficient part of my workflow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git stash` for precisely this. When someone comes to your desk, do a `git stash` to temporarily "shelve" your current work. Check out the other branch, do your thing, and then, when they leave, switch back to your work branch and do `git stash pop`.

Make sure you don't have any changes staged, though - `git stash`, if memory serves, ignores staged changes and untracked files.

Answer (score 3):

After you switch back to the old branch, run `git reset HEAD^` and you'll get back to your previous state. The latest temporary commit will be discarded. If you've pushed that commit, you'll need to --force a new push.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need `git stash`.  [Check out this site for usage.](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing)  Your workflow will look something like this:

`git stash` (stashes your changes for this branch)

`git checkout otherBranch` (then do your work)

`git checkout firstBranch` (returning to the original job)

`git stash apply` (puts your uncommitted changes back)

You can also use `git rebase -i` to get rid of some of your existing dummy commits, [see this](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v1/Git-te-Dallanma-Rebasing-Tekrar-Adresleme).